# How to achieve every data has a double quotes in laravel (Implode)

Tags: php, laravel

Hi developers I have problem  I don't know what type of implode is this, I want to achieve is in every data has a double quotation mark. Ex. "1600","1793","3211" However in my output i look like "1600,1608" so in my sql the query is wrong. so is it possible to make my data look like this "1600","1608" ?

**I will show you guys my sample code:**

```
$selected_store = $request->get('selected_store');
$converted_selected_store = '"'.implode('","',(array)$selected_store).'"';

dd($converted_selected_store);
```

**My Output:**

[image: My Output]

**My Goal:**

```
"1600","1608"
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding, but does `$converted_selected_store = '"'.implode('","',(array)$selected_store).'"';` do what you need? https://3v4l.org/02vGp

Comment: revert the commas, i.e. `'","'` instead of `"','"`

Comment: yah @BrettGregson thats should be the output. but the output shows look like this. "1600,1608"

Comment: @mitkosoft please see my new update

Comment: @BrettGregson please see my new update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously your `$selected_store` is a simple string, so it's quite enough to apply `str_replace()`, like:

```
$converted_selected_store = '"'.str_replace(',','","',$selected_store).'"';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

```
implode(array_map(function($x) { return '"' . $x . '"';}, $selected_store), ',');
```